# Correspondence between variables in the equation $Ax+By = Cx+Dy$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If $Ax+By = Cx+Dy$ is it true to say that there always must be $A=C, B=D$? all variables are real numbers

Comment: What are $A,B $? Matrices? Over a field? Something else?

Comment: @AnyAD they are real numbers

Comment: Then take $x=y=0$. The remaining 'quantities' can be any real numbers.

Comment: Please consider editing your qiestion so that it is clear what exactely you are asking. Otherwise it is a pretty trivial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming all variables are supposed to be real numbers.)

Yes, if your equation is supposed to hold for **all** real numbers $x$ and $y$, then $A=C$ and $B=D$. This line of reasoning is called *comparison of coefficients* or *equating coefficients*.

If your equation only holds for some particular real numbers $x$ and $y$ then this does not have to be true.